# Template Argument Type Deduction Fails with C++11 <type_traits>

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to understand how to use C++(11) `<type_traits>`.

Here's my trivial test program

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class U, class S>
inline U add(typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value,U>::type a,
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed  <S>::value,S>::type b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[], const char * envp[])
{
    unsigned int ui;
    int i;
    auto a = add(ui, i);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with GCC 4.8.1 it errors as

```
/home/per/f.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**, const char**)’:
/home/per/f.cpp:15:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘add(unsigned int&, int&)’
     auto a = add(ui, i);
                       ^
/home/per/f.cpp:15:23: note: candidate is:
/home/per/f.cpp:5:10: note: template<class U, class S> U add(typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, U>::type, typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<S>::value, S>::type)
 inline U add(typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value,U>::type a,
          ^
/home/per/f.cpp:5:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/per/f.cpp:15:23: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U’
     auto a = add(ui, i);
                       ^
```

I have no clue why GCC can't deduce the template parameter `U`. Anybody knows what information my code is missing, that is how I write a program in C++11 that takes a unsigned integral type as first argument and signed integral type as second?

Comment: You cannot decuce types left of a qualifying `::`.

Comment: **14.8.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type [temp.deduct.type]** 5 The non-deduced contexts are: — The nested-name-speciﬁer of a type that was speciﬁed using a qualiﬁed-id.

Comment: Thanks for all nice comments and answers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value,U>::type` is not a deducible context. In order to deduce `U` from this the compiler would need the ability to apply the reverse operation of `std::enable_if`. It doesn't look too hard, that's true, but that's because you are talking about a simple thing like `enable_if`. It would be impossible to require this of every trait, so C++ just plays it cool and does not make any kind of weird rule exceptions: it's not deducible in general, it's not deducible in this one.

You can do it this way instead:

```
template<class U, class S,
         EnableIf<std::is_unsigned<U>, std::is_signed<S>>...>
U add(U a, S b)
```

Or in compilers that don't support that style properly you can just add an extra defaulted argument:

```
template<class U, class S>
U add(U a, S b,
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value
          && std::is_signed<S>::value,void>::type* = nullptr)
```

... or mess up the return type.

```
template<class U, class S>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value
    && std::is_signed<S>::value,U>::type
add(U a, S b)
```

Comment: wow... What is THIS doing? `typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value
          && std::is_signed<S>::value,void>::type* = nullptr`. rvalue to pointer?

Answer (score 8):

You are not giving the compiler a chance to deduce `U` and `S`. You can rewrite your function as follows, and move the SFINAE checks in the template parameter list:

```
template<class U, class S,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value &&
                            std::is_signed  <S>::value
        >::type* = nullptr>
inline U add(U a, S b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e3696ea6aa464171cfe82b80928f9bdb-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336).

Answer (score 4):

You first have to deduce the types *before* you can reason about the types!

It should be:

```
template <typename U, typename S>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value &&
                        std::is_signed<S>::value>, U>::type
add(U u, S s)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to deduce a template parameter from a "nested typedef" expression. That is, it's possible to deduce `U` from  `some_template<U>`, but not from `some_template<U>::type`.

The compiler cannot possibly enumerate all (infinite!) instantiations of `some_template` and see for which of them the nested typedef equals the actual argument type.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
template<class U, class S>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>::value && std::is_signed<S>,U>::type  
add(U a , S b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Personally, i prefer to write enable_if at the return type, because this makes function declaration much clear. And, in addition, makes template deduction work (As in your case).

Comment: Avoid the use of the **inline** keyword. C++ compiler inlines every functions if it thinks is more efficient. Even if you have writed **inline** or not. And, even you puts **inline**, if the compiler thinks that inline that function is not efficient, it won't inline the function. So, not write **inline**. ***You are not better optimizer than the compiler***. Write simple and clear code and let the compiler do its job.